# Полный вывод типа переменной

Tags: c++

При использовании typeid().name() в терминале получаю сокращенный результат типа переменной, хотелось бы полный.

Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

int main()
{
    float s{23.2};
    std::cout << typeid(s).name() << "\n";

    char a{'a'};
    std::cout << typeid(a).name() << "\n";
}
```

Результат:

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp && ./main
f
c
```

Вместо f и c хотелось бы видеть float и char.

Comment: Используйте Visual C++ :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вывод `typeid(...).name()` является компиляторнозависимым. Если хочется красиво-красиво, самый простой способ - воспользоваться библиотекой Boost, там есть для этого библиотека [type index](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/boost_typeindex.html)

Где почитать - https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781787282247/1/01lvl1sec19/getting-a-human-readable-type-name (это примеры с книги)

```
#include <boost/type_index.hpp>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    auto&& x = 42;
    std::cout << "x is "
              << boost::typeindex::type_id_with_cvr<decltype(x)>()
              << std::endl;
}
```

если это не очень подходить, сама библиотека похоже header only, так что ее можно попробовать вытянуть и использовать.

Comment: Большое спасибо, решил использовать Boost, всё в порядке!